# Action update in towerjs controller does not work

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, towerjs

I'll try create a controler in towerjs, but I have an error while updating action:

```
TypeError: Property 'id' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

Here how looks my action:

```
update: ->
  App.User.find @params.id (error, user) =>
    user.updateAttributes @params.user, (error) =>
      if error
        @render "edit", locals: user: user
      else
        @render "show", locals: user: user
```

Console shows me that id parameters is passed:

```
Parameters:
{ user: 
  { name: 'admin',
    email: 'example@domain.com',
    password: '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3' },
  id: '4faa6c614b2ce49b34000001',
  action: 'update',
  format: 'html' }
```

more info: 
The identical actions are built in show, edit, destroy and they are working.
All actions uses the same _form partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
f @params.id (a, b) => ...
```

is equivalent to this:

```
f(@params.id((a,b) => ...))
```

so you're trying to call `@params.id` as a function and passing your `(error,user) =>` function to `@params.id` as its argument. I think you want to pass `@params.id` and `(error,user) =>` to `App.user.find` as two arguments so add a comma:

```
update: ->
  App.User.find @params.id, (error, user) =>
    #---------------------^
```

Comment: I'm so embarrassed that is so easy. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcinRobak: Asking for help isn't embarrassing, banging your head against the wall because you've been staring at something too long to see the obvious and you *don't* want to ask for help is a different story :)

Comment: Nice to hear. You made my day. Greetings! :)